# Linux kernel cannot receive multicast

Tags: linux, multicast

I built a Linux kernel with CONFIG_IP_MULTICAST=y,however no UDP multicast package received in this kernel while UDP unicast works well.

```
ethtool -S eth0 | grep multicast                         
txmulticastframes_g: 0                   
txmulticastframes_gb: 0             
rxmulticastframes_g: 0
```

Any hints how can I solve this problem?

Thx. Forrest G

=================================================================================
Additional:
tcpdump can get the packet

```
root@JHI # ./tcpdump port 3702
device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
-7:-48:-19.4151 IP 192.168.42.212.3702 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 787
-7:-48:-19.4661 IP 192.168.42.212.3702 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 803
^C
2 packets captured
2 padevice eth0 left promiscuous mode
ckets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

I write this WS-devicediscovery function with gSOAP. It works on X86 machine. When running on ARM device, it can send out igmp packet but not receive anything.

```
void wsdd()  
{      
    struct soap *soap_udp;   
    struct ip_mreq mreq;   

    soap_udp=soap_new();  
    soap_init1(soap_udp, SOAP_IO_UDP|SOAP_IO_FLUSH);  

    if (!soap_valid_socket(soap_bind(soap_udp, NULL, 3702, 100)))  
    {      
        soap_print_fault(soap_udp, stderr);  
    }  

    mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("239.255.255.250");  
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);  

    if(setsockopt(soap_ud->master,IPPROTO_IP,IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,&mreq,sizeof(mreq))==-1)     {  
        perror("membership error\n");  
    }

    int loop = 1;  
    int sock_opt = 1;
    if ((setsockopt(soap_udp->master, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void *) &sock_opt,  
                    sizeof (sock_opt))) == -1) {  
        printf("setsockopt\n");  
    }  
    if ((setsockopt(soap_udp->master, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP,  
                       &loop, sizeof (loop))) == -1) {  
        printf("setsockopt\n");  
    }

    while(1){  
        soap_accept(soap_udp);
        soap_serve(soap_udp);   
        soap_end(soap_udp); 
    }  
}
```

Then I have tried these things but still not work

```
route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 eth0
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter
```

Comment: Please include the code you've written to receieve UDP multicast (a program needs to use the `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`  socket option to join a multicast group).

Comment: Are you trying to send multicast and receive it on the same box?

Comment: No, I'm trying to listen to an external multicast and response unicast message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by changing..

```
ifconfig eth0 promisc
```

Can anyone explain the principle?

Comment: I guess the ability to catch multicast by your NIC is pretty much dependent on its driver. Since IPv4 multicast packets are specified to use specific link destination address derived from target multicast group when transported over ethernet, you must somewhat make your NIC accept ethernet frames with those addresses. AFAIK modern NICs are able to have up to 4 or 8 different MAC addresses they will receive for, but your driver has to be able to set them to do so. Otherwise, you can use promiscuous mode, which basically means NIC will not filter incoming frames based on MAC address.
Driver bug.